# different reaction of application in scanning beacons on different devices

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, altbeacon

i have an application to scan BLE beacons around. I've used Altbeacon library to do that. When i run it on my Nexus 6p it finds some beacons but when i run it on galaxy s9 or Kindle fire HD 8 number of beacons it found is always zero. Here is my code:

```
override fun onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.removeAllRangeNotifiers()
    beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(object : RangeNotifier {
        override fun didRangeBeaconsInRegion(beacons: Collection<Beacon>, region: Region) {
            Log.i("ranging" , "beacons size:" + beacons.size)

            for (b in beacons) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),b.id1.toString() + " beacon I see is about " + b.rssi + " away.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    })

    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(Region("myRangingUniqueId", Identifier.parse(""), null, null))
    } catch (e: RemoteException) {
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val binding : com.example.attendancecheck_v1.databinding.FragmentTeacherScanningBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater, R.layout.fragment_teacher_scanning, container, false)


    beaconManager.bind(this)

    setHasOptionsMenu(true)

    return binding.root
}
```

By the way, I installed a beacons simulator on my devices and it can scan for beacons but in my code, the output is zero on those devices.

Comment: Did you request and obtain location permission from the user?

Comment: @davidgyoung yes I've done it in android manifest and my location is on when opening app on those devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check it with this region:

```
beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null))
```